# Android ActionBar background colors.xml not working

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm a beginner in android development. And I'm following the training on developer.android.com. But I'm having problem changing actionbar background color right now.
I have the error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@colors/orange').  styles.xml  /ActionBarColor/res/values  line 17 Android AAPT Problem
```

when I'm refering to res/values/colors.xml from my res/values/styles.xml

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name ="orange">#FF8800</color>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/myActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name = "myActionBar" parent = "Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name ="android:background">@colors/orange</item> <!--Error Here-->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

I read almost every thread on this but found no clue. My code looks exactly same as the others, as far as I can tell. Please help me. The project target is API19, min ver is API11

added themes.xml as the website says, error stays

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

        <item name="android:background">@colors/orange</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@colors/orange</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, you're using the AppCompat library on your Android project, so you should only use AppCompat resources for theming. Right from the Android training pages on how to [Style the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html), in the section ["Customize the Background"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then apply your theme to your entire app or to individual activities:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```

1. Create an style for the Action Bar based on any existent AppCompat themes and define the `background` item (for appcompat apps) - `MyActionBar` in the above example.
2. Create an style that'll be used by your project that applies the previously created Action bar style, and define the `actionBarStyle` item (for appcompat apps) - `CustomActionBarTheme` in the above example.

You would really want to read through the [Android Training Pages](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html), they're pretty well explained; and you also have the [Android API Guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and the [Android API Reference Pages](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) just in case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But here I was trying to just change the background color instead of to set the background to some image in drawable dir. I guess my question is, why my colors.xml is not referable. Are you saying if I use appcompat_v7, then I cant refer to colors.xml in my own project package?

Comment: Of course you can replace the `drawable` resource for a `color`.

Comment: I added a themes.xml as the website says, and used exactly code except for replacing @drawable/actionbar_background with @colors/orange. Error stays. See my edited question

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your project? (Project > Clean...). You can also try specifying a hex color directly instead of a resource.

Comment: It turns out I misunderstood @blablabla as the the name of the xml file. So I used @colors/orange instead of @color/orange because I thought my "orange" item is in colors.xml. Noob misunderstanding, but no one pointed it out lol. Thank you